# Golang SQL package jsonb operator

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb

In sql package for postgresql jsonb how can I use the `@>` operator with a string query for example

- `WHERE data @> '{"stringdata": $1}'` or
- `WHERE data @> '{"stringdata": "$1"}'` doesn’t work

The alternative is `data->>'string_data' = $1` which I don’t prefer for multiple statements

Error is:

```
    "Message": "invalid input syntax for type json",
    "Detail": "Token \"$\" is invalid.”,
    "Where": "JSON data, line 1: $...",
    "Routine": "report_invalid_token"
```

Comment: You're using "smart quotes", which will not work. Use a plain text editor, not a word processor, when writing queries. Please also show the *exact text* of the error message.

Comment: @CraigRinger added the error message. Could you show an example of plain text editor? And why doesn't smart quotes work?

Comment: Apparently that was an artifact of the question editing, and the original text has base ASCII double quotes (`"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't interpolate inside strings, but you can [build a JSON object](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) using `json_build_object` or `json_object`:

```
SELECT data FROM test
WHERE data @> json_build_object('stringdata', $1::text, 'foo', $2::int)::jsonb;
```

This is basically an equivalent of

```
SELECT data FROM test
WHERE data @> '{"stringdata":"$1","foo":$2}';
```

Comment: Coudl you provide am example of json object with multiple keys as well